# What do the following commands do in Pandas?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, machine-learning

I was just looking at some code for Random Forests, and came across these two lines.
Let's assume I have a pandas dataframe 'df' that consists of 12 columns.

What will the following code return

```
X =  df.iloc[:,0:11].values 
Y = df.iloc[:, 12].values
```

Comment: Read the Pandas docs. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate a dataframe to consider:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5, 2)),
                      columns=['Col 1', 'Col 2'])
```

If we print the dataframe, you get:

```py
>>> print(df)
   Col 1  Col 2
0      8      4
1      6      4
2      7      5
3      9      6
4      1      5
```

To determine what the `:` does, lets consider

```py
>>> print(df.iloc[:,0])
0    8
1    6
2    7
3    9
4    1
```

which appears to produce every single row in the 0-th column.

Lets try another example:

```py
>>> print(df.iloc[0:3,0])
0    8
1    6
2    7
```

It looks like that gives the rows at position 0 through position 2 in the 0-th column.

So, from playing with those examples, you can infer that `:` returns the full dimension.  In your example, it returns all rows since the `:` comes first.  The `0:11` returns columns 0 through column 10.  The `12` returns the 12th column.

Answer (score 0):

```
X =  df.iloc[:,0:11].values
```

The above line will return **all rows** and columns starting from **1st till 11th column** (11th column inclusive) in the form of an array.

```
Y = df.iloc[:, 12].values
```

The above line returns **13th** column values (**not 12th column**) in the form of an array of the data frame

**Example :**

Sample dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,120,size=(5, 14)), columns=[k+l for k,l in zip(list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMN'), [str(i) for i in range(1,15)])]) #Just tried to name the columns with letters combined with numbers for convenient tracking.
df
```

[image]

```
X =  df.iloc[:,0:11]#.values 
X
```

[image]

```
Y = df.iloc[:, 12].values
Y
```

[image]